# How to choose OpenAPI generator endpoints generation?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have an API define in a swagger template file .yaml. This file create for me the Swagger View.
With this file, it generate the default API using OpenAPI generator.

For example, in my swagger I have 3 endpoints (this is not my API, it's only for example): 
`GET /hello` 
`POST /name` 
`GET /name`

Using OpenAPI generator, I would like to know if it's possible to exclude endpoints.
For example, I would like to generate only two endpoints:
`POST /name` 
`GET /name`

Is there a parameter to do that ?

I made some research about it, and i find that:
[Is it possible to exclude paths in Openapi code generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728705/is-it-possible-to-exclude-paths-in-openapi-code-generation)

But there is no specifications about how we can really exclude endpoints.

> For example, I need to remove `GET /test` but keep `POST /test`, and not remove all the `/test` endpoints.